# Running java jar file returning Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am trying to run an executable and every time I run java -jar "example file" I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sgs_grahpical_utility : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

It says my Java version is "1.7.0_95" but I downloaded jdk1.8.0_91 and in the netbeans java platform it is using the jdk 1.8. Im not sure whats wrong because if I run another project the same way, it is perfectly fine.Im using netbeans IDE 8.1.

Update: I changed the way I did this project, I don't have a package like I do for the other one that works fine when running. Im wondering if this has something to do with it

Comment: what is in your classpath ? You have to have java 8 available in your classpath. You can test the version by typing "java -version" in cmdline.

Comment: when doing java -version it says im runnign 1.7.0_95

Comment: thats the problem. If you are in windows, open my computer/properties/advanced system settings. Select Advanced tab in new window, click Environemnt variables. ON System varaibles list, select classpath  and click edit. find your current java path , remove it and replace it with java 8 path ( path up to bin folder).

Comment: How would I do that on a linux open suse machine?

Comment: Use export command. something like  `export PATH=/<path to JAVA 8 installation>/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not configured the JRE properly at runtime configuration.

Select 
    Run configuration > JRE Tab > Select the valid Java version via 'Installed JREs' option.